Casting derivate type to base type still shows properties from derivate type
Below is a HUGE simplification of my actual code:
var a = new A();
var b = (B)a;

Console.WriteLine(b);

public class A : B
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Name";
}
public class B
{
    public string Test { get; set; } = "Test";
}

Problem is that even if I cast instance a to type B properties of type A are still being visible. This is causing me some problems because such properties are still getting serialized and returned as endpoint response in Postman.
Question: How can I cast a as B to get rid of properties of typa A?
I tried something this:
var b = new B() { Test = a.Test };
and this obviously works but creating completely new object doesn't seem to be optimal solution.
EDIT:
Console.WriteLine("B: {0}", JsonSerializer.Serialize(b));

Above code will return only properties from B but when I tested this in the Postman properties from A are also returned. It seems that default serialization that is being done under the hood in .NET Web Api is doing something more then simply JsonSerializer.Serialize(b) and this is causing properties A to also be returned in Postman.
EDIT 2:
As NPras mentioned in one of the comment result of serialization depends on which serialization framework is being used.
Newtonsoft: Properties from type A i B are being serialized.
System.Text.Json: Only properties from type B are being serialized.
So one needs to be extra careful here.

You can control the serialization. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-9.0#configure-systemtextjson-based-formatters-2 Or even serialize it yourself and write the response body.

Well yeah it seems this problem comes down to some serialisation issue. But I'm still surprised default serializer actually returns properties from A even though 'a' variable was explicitly casted as B. Not intuitive at all.

The serializer wouldn't really know what your local variable type is.  You sent it an object, and it serialized the properties.

It makes sense but still it's kinda surprising behaviour that serializer is variable type agnostic.I guess I will fetch serializer source code and take a look of how it works :)

Wait, are you using (or told the app to use) Json.NET (a.k.a. Newtonsoft)? Because System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize() doesn't serialize the inherited properties, but Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject() does.

If this is a WebAPI you should probably post the code for the request handler, at least the signature. I'm not an expert on asp.Net, but it might depend on return types etc. An option might be to just do the serialization yourself, since you figured out that part already, and return a string.

Indeed my question is not properly defined. I will refactor it later in time.

What's not intuitive? B is a A. That's what inheritance means! Every instance of type B includes all the properties of type A. So of course the serializer is going to output it.

@JimMischel actually the fact that Newtonsoft is serializing properties of type A and  System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer doesn't serializing them is quite confusing, don't you think? If that's so intuitive why those two works in totally different way on default settings?

@Fernell85: Your question doesn't mention anything about Newtonsoft. I still don't fully understand your issue because you haven't provided an example that clearly shows it.

@JimMischel I'm just saying this case is far from being intuitive as you suggested it. And one of the reason is that different serializers treat this case completely differently. It's actually super easy to create a potential bug here.

The reason you see an object serialized as a B even though you cast it to an A is that the cast doesn't create a new object or change the object in any way. And JsonSerializer.Serialize takes an object as its parameter. It doesn't matter what you think the object is. The serializer inspects the object to get its type and such.

@JimMischel First of all I'm not casting as A. I'm casting as B. Secondly the serialization result depends on serializer framework that you are using.

You won't go away from creating a new object (I mean internally somewhere new object will still be created), if we are talking about API responses, a good approach is using DTO objects, that is simple data class, that contain all of the needed properties and even if you decide to extend your base object, you will not get those props as a result of endpoint, only adding those to DTO will do.

"You won't go away from creating a new object" - yes I'm suspecting the same here unfortunately.
In real life those A and B classes are DTOs. Problem is I don't need properties from class A and creating new object of class B seems like really heavy to accomplish something this simple.

@Fernell85 In that case, you can try to use AutoMapper if that is possible, it will resolve all of your problems. If not, try custom JSON serialization, a little dirtier solution as for me, but it will work

using AutoMapper is considered a bad practice nowadays. https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/why-i-dont-use-automapper/ And using JSon serialization is even more heavy operation then manually creating new B object. But thanks for your suggestions.

@Fernell85, yes, but it's serializing to JSON when making a response, so you're doing it already. Also, you can do an approach with dto for each response (CreateUserDTO, not just UserDTO for example)

I'm not doing serialization directly. It's being done automatically under the hood by .NET Web API.

Anyway if no one else will provied any better way of doing this then creating new instance of B I will accept your answer "You won't go away from creating a new object" as accepted. But lets wait few more days.
